# URL Rewrite and design files

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I am coding a portal which has multi categories.

Example:

```
http://localhost/portal/cats

http://localhost/portal/dogs
```

Ofcourse this is possible with URL rewrite

Like this

```
RewriteRule ^cats$ /portal/index.php?cat=cats
```

Ok so this works alright.

Problem happens when I try to access page like this

```
http://localhost/portal/cats/black-cat-22
```

My url rewrite is:

```
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)-([0-9]+)$ /portal/page.php?cat=cats&id=$2
```

Why?

Because all my CSS & image files are located in http://localhost/portal/elements and not in http://localhost/portal/cats/elements - which is not even real directory.

So I am looking for solution how to do rewrite if URL includes /elements/ it reads from /portal/elements not from any other directory.

If something is unclear, free to ask below.

Cheers and happy new year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's where the html `<base>` tag comes to the rescue :)

Add something like this as first line in your HTML head:

```
<base href="http://localhost/portal/" > <!-- or end with /> if XHTML -->
```

Then everything you reference with relative URLs will be relative to that base.

So you can reference your CSS using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="elements/stylesheet.css" />
```

Which should resolve to: `http://localhost/portal/elements/stylesheet.css`, no matter what URL you're currently visiting (be that `portal/cats`, or `portal/cats/some-black-cat` etc.

Comment: woah thank youuuuuuuuuu :P
didn't know about tag - stupid me :D
again thank you and I wish you really nice holidays.

Comment: @hakre you're right.. the relative link should be without the slash at the beginning. My bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

As you map the URLs when they come into your application, you need to map back the URLs when they "return" from the application.

This either can be done at the point where you create the URLs for the output, e.g. define your base url and assign the local part:

```
$baseUrl = 'http://localhost/portal/';
$localUrl = 'elements/image.png';
$fullUrl = $baseUrl . $localUrl;
```

Or you have your own internal URL specification and it get's mapped globally with an [output filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164392/making-all-php-file-output-pass-through-a-filter-file-before-being-displayed) (PHP way of doing that).

As you use `.htaccess` to map the URLs into your application, use it as well to map them back. This can be done with [`mod_substitute`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html) easily.

In your application you use a special URL sheme, e.g. called `site://`, it will be replaced with your servers base URL `http://localhost/portal/` automatically then. The `.htaccess` code:

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute s/site:\/\//http://localhost/portal//nq
</Location>
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about this but this would require a lot of recoding.

Because i just include() .html templates and with url rewrite it would be faster.

Comment: @user1102979: I added an example that shows how an output filter could work with the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks man but this solution is far too advanced for me.But I am sure it will help someone else someday.
But thanks for effort and happy new year.

Comment: It's only showing the general picture, sure. With `<base>` based rewriting, the browser will do that for you.